# How to control the order that after_request handlers are executed?

Tags: python, flask

I have two after_request handlers.  In my case, I need one to fire before the next.

```
@app.after_request
    def after_request_check_something(response):
        # do something
        return response

@app.after_request
    def after_request_compress(response):
        # do something
        return response
```

In my case, I want compress to go first, then check_something.  But they are firing in reverse.

If it matters, in my actual code, these two handlers are not consecutively declared like this.  They are each in different modules that are installed at different times.

**How can I control the order of execution?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** user8808265's answer looks more correct than mine.

From [the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.after_request), it does not appear that the execution of these `after_request` handlers can be ordered. The implementation has the handlers stored in a dictionary which is inherently unordered.

I suggest making a separate handler that calls both in the correct order, something like:

```
def after_request_check_something(response):
    # do something
    return response


def after_request_compress(response):
    # do something
    return response

@app.after_request
def after_request_combined(response):
    response1 = after_request_compress(response)
    return after_request_check_something(response1)
```

Comment: If they're stored in a dictionary then a possible solution could be [use Python 3.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/dictionaries-are-ordered-in-cpython-3-6) ;)

Comment: There's a confusion here. This answer is **wrong** and shouldn't be the accepted answer. The hooks dictionary maps **blueprints** to an **ordered list of hook functions**. It doesn't map the hook functions directly. Global app hooks are stored as a list, into the `None` key of the `after_request_funcs` dictionary. According to the implementation, `after_request` hooks are executed in reversed declaration order, just as noticed by the OP. This contrasts with `before_request` hooks which are executed in order of declaration. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 13):

Flask's `after_request` hooks are indeed executed in the reversed order of their declaration. Conversely, `before_request` hooks are executed in the order of their declaration.

If `after_request` hooks are declared on a blueprint, those are executed in reversed declaration order, **before** global `after_request` hooks. If `before_request` hooks are declared on a blueprint, those are executed in declaration order, **after** global `before_request` hooks.

See [preprocess_request](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/dfd3619d6f8796d48fc4e32f819cec9e8aa59156/flask/app.py#L2083) and [process_response](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/dfd3619d6f8796d48fc4e32f819cec9e8aa59156/flask/app.py#L2106) source code for implementation details.